# How check and uncheck of a checkbox can show and hide a div

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox with ID GlandularFever and on click (which checks it) I can get it to show another DIV with data-field `name="GlandularDetails"`. Though on un-check, how do I get it to hide that div again? If data-field `name="GlandularDetails hidden = true` then show, else if data-field `name="GlandularDetails hidden = false` then hide.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#GlandularFever").click(function(){

  $(document.querySelectorAll('[data-field name="GlandularDetails"]')).show(100); 
  hidden = false;

  });  
});
</script>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-4">
                <input value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="GlandularFever" id="GlandularFever"/>
                <label for="GlandularFever">Glandular Fever</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" data-field-name="GlandularDetails">
        <label class="control-label">Details</label>
        <textarea rows="3" id="GlandularDetails" name="GlandularDetails" maxlength="100"  class="form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to show/hide div based on checkbox value right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#GlandularFever').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('[data-field name="GlandularDetails"]').show(100);
    } else {
      $('[data-field name="GlandularDetails"]').hide(100);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery method [`.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
var glandularDetails = $('[data-field-name="GlandularDetails"]');
glandularDetails.hide();

$("#GlandularFever").click(function() {
  glandularDetails.toggle(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-4">
      <input value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="GlandularFever" id="GlandularFever" />
      <label for="GlandularFever">Glandular Fever</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12" data-field-name="GlandularDetails">
  <label class="control-label">Details</label>
  <textarea rows="3" id="GlandularDetails" name="GlandularDetails" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to alternate between hidden and visible.

Also, avoid `document.querySelectorAll` when using jQuery.  jQuery automatically handles that:

```js
$("#GlandularFever").click(function() {
  $('[data-field-name="GlandularDetails"]').toggle(100);
});
```

```css
div.form-group {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-4">
      <input value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="GlandularFever" id="GlandularFever" />
      <label for="GlandularFever">Glandular Fever</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12" data-field-name="GlandularDetails">
  <label class="control-label">Details</label>
  <textarea rows="3" id="GlandularDetails" name="GlandularDetails" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code and run

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div[data-field-name=GlandularDetails]").hide();
 $("#GlandularFever").click(function(){
    
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
    $("div[data-field-name=GlandularDetails]").show();
   }
   else
   {
    $("div[data-field-name=GlandularDetails]").hide();
   }
  });  
});
</script>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-4">
                <input value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="GlandularFever" id="GlandularFever"/>
                <label for="GlandularFever">Glandular Fever</label>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" data-field-name="GlandularDetails">
        <label class="control-label">Details</label>
        <textarea rows="3" id="GlandularDetails" name="GlandularDetails" maxlength="100"  class="form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
```

.